Can't find Bulk 2.0 API status file result with failed results in Jenkins, is there any way to get these results?
Can't find Bulk 2.0 API status file result with failed results in Jenkins, is there any way to get these results?
Looks like there are not present in workspaces since the new build has rewritten any data being stored there

If you know the Job Id, you can use Bulk REST API to get the failed results
Perform GET request
https://{{Domain}}/services/data/v59.0/jobs/ingest/{{jid}}/failedResults with headers
-H Content-Type: application/json -H 'Authorization: Bearer {{sid}}'
and you will be able to download the failed results file even if it is not available in CI/CD system.
Substitute {{Domain}} with your actual my domain, {{jid}} with job id and {{sid}} with your session id.
